# Change number format from 10000 to 10,000 android

Tags: java, android, number-formatting

I want to ask, so I have an input form where it includes the amount of income with an example format of 250,000,000 then I make a detailed view to see the results already inputted but in the input form 250 only appears as shown below

[here detail activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojxiY.png)

here my code in detail activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detailbisnis);

    nmbisnislain = findViewById(R.id.nmbisnislain);
    nmusaha = findViewById(R.id.nmusaha);
    merek = findViewById(R.id.merek);
    jumlah_karyawan = findViewById(R.id.jumlah_karyawan);
    jml_cabang = findViewById(R.id.jml_cabang);
    omset_tahunan = findViewById(R.id.omset_tahunan);
    no_tlp = findViewById(R.id.no_tlp);
    facebook = findViewById(R.id.facebook);
    instagram = findViewById(R.id.instagram);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    Intent a = getIntent();
    String namas = a.getStringExtra("nm_bisnis_lain");
    String usaha = a.getStringExtra("nm_usaha");
    String merekss = a.getStringExtra("merk");
    String karyawans = a.getStringExtra("jml_karyawan");
    String cabangs = a.getStringExtra("jml_cabang");
    String omsed = a.getStringExtra("omset_tahunan");
    String nope = a.getStringExtra("no_tlp");
    String faceboo = a.getStringExtra("facebook");
    String insta = a.getStringExtra("instagram");



    nmbisnislain.setText("Bisnis Lain :"+namas);
    nmusaha.setText("Nama Usaha : "+usaha);
    merek.setText("Merk : "+merekss);
    jumlah_karyawan.setText("Jumlah Karyawan :"+karyawans);
    jml_cabang.setText("Jumlah Cabang :"+cabangs);

    //here
    omset_tahunan.setText("Omset Tahunan :"+omsed);

    no_tlp.setText("Nomor Telepon :"+nope);
    facebook.setText("Facebook :"+faceboo);
    instagram.setText("Instagram :"+insta);


}
```

So I want the textview (omset_tahunan) to display to 250,000,000 instead of 250

I have tried number format and decimal format but the result is null

please help me hehe ..

Comment: DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
String yourFormattedString = formatter.format(100000);  im follow this code but i'm confused :3

Comment: *"but i'm confused :3"* - Why are you confused?  It would help if you showed us **all** of the relevant code (as an MCVE), and if you put it into the Question, not the comments, and not into a link to an image, etc.

Comment: I have entered my code in the question, and the format you want to change is omset_tahunan

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with `DecimalFormat` and different formats it can print for possible numbers using `Hash(#), Comma(,) and Dot(.)`

```
String number = "1000000000";
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
System.out.println(f.format(Double.parseDouble(number)));
```

Output would be `1,000,000,000`